# Jhipster - Cannot access mircosevice resource through gateway - 404 not found err

Tags: jhipster, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

Using Jhipster Registry, Jhipster UAA, Jhipster Gateway App and Jhipster Microservice App.

I am trying to access my microservices enpoints through a gateway application I created. Everything looks good when I look at the logs but when I try to access the microservices resources in the gateway. I get:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

AND

**Cannot GET /api/menu-items**

GATEWAY LOGS

[image: Gateway Logs]

[image]

RESULT OF HITTING ENDPOINT
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The port that I was using for the microservice was being used by another application. Ergo, I solved this issue by killing the other app.